# Metric space gluing: the double-disk boundary metric

Tags: metric-spaces, quotient-spaces

This may not be well posed, but I hope you get the idea...

If two closed, flat disks of equal size are glued at their boundary, i.e. an equivalence is established between the two boundaries, I believe that the equivalence should be an isometry - i.e. distance preserving.

Now, the metric is defined for the interior and the boundary of each disk, and is flat, but the result of the gluing (a flattened sphere) is not flat and has infinite curvature at the points that were on the boundaries of the two disks, so the metric is no longer flat at those points.

Can someone explain how the metric "changes" in the process of gluing. Was it, contrary to my assumption, somehow undefined on the boundary previously.

I think I am mssing something fundamental here...

Comment: There is indeed a natural metric on this space, called a "path metric". This metric has nonnegative curvature in the sense of Alexandrov, which is indeed concentrated at the boundary circle of the disk. There are some textbooks covering this staff, if you like I can give some references.

Comment: Yes, I would appreciate those references... and if you can expand on your comments (as an answer rather than further comment perhaps) that would also be welcome.

Comment: @MoisheCohen If path metric = intrinsic metric, then I am aware of that but specifically don't see how it gives the result stated, i.e. I don't see how the gluing introduces any shorter path that makes the induced metric different - except possibly between points that were previously disjoint, and that doesn't seem to account for the location of the curvature.

Comment: http://www.ams.org/books/gsm/033/gsm033-endmatter.pdf

Comment: @MoisheCohen. I actually have that but I assume you recommend "A Course in Metric Geometry" for something specific it contains other than preface, contents and index... could you specify the reference within that answers the question?

Answer (score -1):

You are confused: Topological 'gluing' together of two spaces which happen to have metrics *does not automatically* create a combined metric on the combined space.  You have to explicitly define the new metric from the old by stipulating how to compute the distance between a point in the interior of one disk from a point in the interior of the other (or create a fresh metric from scratch).

Incidentally, 'curvature' is not a property of the intrinsic metric; it is a property of how the space is embedded in a larger space with a metric of its own (example: the surface of a cylinder, with respect to the obvious geodesic metric, is not considered to be curved [the Gaussian curvature is zero]).